# "Report item not linked to a dataset"...but it is

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I am getting this error in the expression editor for a chart control.

Category - Fields
Item - 
'Fields selection frame' is where I see the error

The chart ***IS*** linked to a dataset though and it works too; how else would the chart be populated with meangingful data when I run it? :)

Does anyone know why this occurs?

[pic not supplied due to corp firewall]

Comment: Bizarrely, I tried deploying the report despite the error....and it works!

Comment: Perhaps unsurprisingly, confirmed on 2008 R2. I have access to 2014 so will need to try that and see whether this is still an issue (I assume/hope not). Good to know I'm not the only one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug in SSRS i.e. the fact that it works anyway but displays an error in the expression editor

Answer (score 3):

It only works when you remove the filter.  Its broke, if you put a filter in you get the erroneous error message and no data in your chart.  If you remove the filter you get your chart but of course not filtered the way you want.  I'm using 2008.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this I can confirm that this still occurs in SQL Server 2008 SP2 (Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 10.0.4000.0) and also if the report is opened in Report Builder 3.0 (2008 R2).